# Hitting an API from Django admin Panel

Tags: django, django-admin, django-admin-actions

In Django admin Panel. I have a model which has fields like userID, name, status. I want to call an API (e.g:- www.xyx.com?user=userID&status='approved') when status="approved" is selected and click on save button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override the [`save_model()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model) method in `ModelAdmin`. From there, you can make the API request before delegating the save operation itself to the parent class.

For example, assuming your model class is called `MyModel`, and that you are using the [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library to call the API:

```
from django.contrib import admin
import requests

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if obj.status == 'approved':
            # Make the API call
            requests.get('http://www.example.com', params={'user': obj.userID, 'status': 'approved'})
        # Delegate the save to the parent class
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```